# Haskell - Remove the Nth odd number from a list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I've been wondering if there is any way to remove the Nth odd number from a list

For example:

```
removeOdd 2 [2,4,3,6,5,8] == [2,4,3,6,8]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 basic cases, list is empty and list is not empty. For list being not empty you have 3 sub cases, n == 1 (which means you need to remove the next odd number) and the number is odd, n > 1 and the number is odd, and the number is not odd.

```hs
removeNthOdd _ [] = []
removeNthOdd n (x:xs)
  | x `mod` 2 == 1 && n == 1 = xs
  | x `mod` 2 == 1 = ...
  | otherwise = ...
```

I have left those 2 cases for you to implement.

You can also add a case where `n` is zero. In that case you can just return the list early, because there isn't a of an odd number being the zeroest.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion should help you with this:

```
removeNthOdd :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
-- basecase of an empty list
removeNthOdd n [] = []
removeNthOdd n (x : xs)
  -- odd number to remove is found, just return the rest of the list
  | odd x && n == 1 = xs
  -- odd number found, but not the one we want to remove
  -- so we decrement n to reach the case before
  | odd x && n > 0 = x : removeNthOdd (n - 1) xs
  -- x is even, so just continue
  | otherwise = x : removeNthOdd n xs

*Main> removeNthOdd 2 [2,4,3,6,5,8] == [2,4,3,6,8]
True
```

Consider asking a specific question the next time and what you did by yourself, e.g. paste some code, to reach your goal.